# Express JS : rewrite url look like /article_name-id.html

Tags: url-rewriting, express

I'm building the new version of a website and I have to take charge of older urls looks like :
http://website.com/article_title_rewrited-article_id.html

Actually, I try to work about something like that :

```
app.get('/:title\-:id([0-9]).html', function...);
```

But of course it fails !

Can I do this type of rewriting using expressjs, or have I to use another method to port the url rewriting ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to use the Express url route parser as well as REGEX expressions, unfortunately this doesn't work, you have to use one or the other.

Remove the string and place with a REGEX pattern. Then the groups in the REGEX expressions will be available at req.params[0] and req.params[1].

```
app.get(/(.+)\.html/, function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect(req.params[0].substring(0, req.params[0].length - 5)); // -5 for length of '.html'
});
```

I believe that should (untested) sort it generically for all .html extensions if that can be a helpful guide :)